# Unsolved Perfect Coverings

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I went through the [La Jolla Covering Repository](https://www.ccrwest.org/cover/low_tab.html) and [wrote about perfect coverings](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/921122) in a community post.

UNSOLVED:
C(36,6,2), C(46,6,2), C(51,6,2),
C(61,6,2), C(81,6,2), C(43,7,2),
C(85,7,2), C(37,7,3), C(42,6,4)

The above are the cases where a perfect covering hasn't been proven impossible, but a solution has not yet been found.  I was especially surprised by C(43,7,2) not being solved.

Is there a list somewhere of unsolved combinatorial problems of this sort?  Are any of these cases vulnerable to computer attacks or impossibility proofs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that I'm correct to interpret your "*perfect coverings*" as Steiner systems, there's a list of known status for possible parameters elsewhere in the La Jolla Covering Repository: https://www.ccrwest.org/cover/steiner.html

Note in particular:

> 36    6   2       Does not exist (see Colbourn and Mathon)
>   43    7   2       Does not exist (see Colbourn and Mathon)
>   37    7   3       Does not exist (see Colbourn and Mathon)

The reference is to **Steiner Systems**, Charles J. Colbourn and Rudolf Mathon, in *Handbook of Combinatorial Designs*, second edition, (2007) pp. 102-110.

Comment: Dan Gordon migrated the La Jolla covering design repository to [his new site](https://www.dmgordon.org/cover/), so it might be a good idea to update your link.